# Not able to configure Bugzilla for sending emails from intranet SMTP server

Tags: email, smtp, bugzilla, postfix-mta, zimbra

I am setting up a Bugzilla server. I am getting following error when I submit email delivery method description on Bugzilla page during configuration.

> The new value for smtpserver is invalid: Cannot connect to 10.71.2.16.

**Email delivery method description**

```
mail_delivery_method: SMTP
mailfrom: bugzilla@mydomain.com
use_mailer_queue: off
smtpserver: 10.71.2.16 
(I have also tried putting domain name, all ports such as 25, 465, 587)
smtp_username: bugzilla@mydomain.com
smtp_password: <password for user bugzilla@mydomain.com>
smtp_ssl: I have tried On and Off both but no sucsess
smtp_debug: On (but not sure where it generates logs. 
Checked /var/log/apache2/. But nothing over there.)
```

**My environment**

```
Ubuntu: 16.04 Server (Internal Server IP: 10.71.6.45)
Bugzilla: 5.0.3 (Internal Server IP: 10.71.6.45)
SMTP: Zimbra Release 8.0.6_GA_5922.RHEL6_64 RHEL6_64 FOSS edition. 
(Internal Server IP: 10.71.2.16)
This Zimbra is hosted on a remote server (10.71.2.16) in Intranet. 
It is sending and receiving emails successfully from long time without any issues.
```

**/var/log/zimbra.log on (server 10.71.2.16 where SMTP is hosted)**

```
Dec  1 00:25:22 email postfix/smtps/smtpd[18064]: connect from unknown[10.71.6.45]
Dec  1 00:25:22 email postfix/smtps/smtpd[18064]: SSL_accept error from unknown[10.71.6.45]: lost connection
Dec  1 00:25:22 email postfix/smtps/smtpd[18064]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[10.71.6.45]
Dec  1 00:25:22 email postfix/smtps/smtpd[18064]: disconnect from unknown[10.71.6.45]
```

**/var/log/maillog (on server 10.71.2.16 where SMTP is hosted)**

```
Dec  1 00:24:36 email postfix/smtps/smtpd[18064]: connect from unknown[10.71.6.45]
Dec  1 00:24:36 email postfix/smtps/smtpd[18064]: SSL_accept error from unknown[10.71.6.45]: lost connection
Dec  1 00:24:36 email postfix/smtps/smtpd[18064]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[10.71.6.45]
Dec  1 00:24:36 email postfix/smtps/smtpd[18064]: disconnect from unknown[10.71.6.45]
```

**However when I am sending email from command prompt with below command emails are getting delivered**

> echo "This is Email Body. This email is sent from Ubuntu Server 10.71.6.45 using SMTP server 10.71.2.16" | mailx -v -r "bugzilla@mydomain.com" -s "Bugzilla test mail - This is the subject" -S smtp="10.71.2.16" -S smtp-use-starttls -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp-auth-user="bugzilla@mydomain.com" -S smtp-auth-password="bugzilla@mydomain.com-emailid-password" -S ssl-verify=ignore test@mydomain.com

**/var/www/html/bugzilla/Bugzilla/Mailer.pm snippet**

```
if ($method eq "SMTP") {
    my ($host, $port) = split(/:/, Bugzilla->params->{'smtpserver'}, 2);
    $transport = Bugzilla->request_cache->{smtp} //=
      Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::Persistent->new({
        host  => $host,
        defined($port) ? (port => $port) : (),
        sasl_username => Bugzilla->params->{'smtp_username'},
        sasl_password => Bugzilla->params->{'smtp_password'},
        helo => $hostname,
        ssl => Bugzilla->params->{'smtp_ssl'},
        debug => Bugzilla->params->{'smtp_debug'} });
}
```

I have tried all possible combinations. But it always give following error in Bugzilla

> The new value for smtpserver is invalid: Cannot connect to 10.71.2.16.

What is that which I am doing wrong or am I missing?

Comment: The error message looks like it tries to use SSL but something is wrong. Do you have a valid certificate, on both ends?

Comment: @tripleee I am able to send emails from command line from server where Bugzilla is installed. I have modified my question with the command  which successfully sends emails from command prompt. About certificate: Bugzilla server is setup by me. I have not installed certificate explicitly. However, I am not sure whether it has got installed during setup. And intranet SMTP server is there from long and it is sending and receiving emails successfully from many years. I am not sure whether it has any certificate. It can be accessed as mail client from intranet browser without HTTPS.